# Windows phone - Common User Interface for pages

Tags: xaml, user-interface, windows-phone-8

What is the best realization of UI in windows phone application? For example, I want to add to all pages TextBlock control in the top of screen and avoid code dublicates. May be something with my custom page class, inheriting PhoneApplicationPage? Or any better solution?

EDIT:
I found solution with inheritance here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jschaffe/archive/2011/03/03/creating-a-custom-base-page-for-windows-phone-7.aspx , but I need to pass LayoutRoot grid to base class to make xaml content inside.. Is there any ability to do it? I thought about passing LayoutRoot as base constructor argument, but it doesn't work

```
public partial class EventsPage : GMPage { 
    public EventsPage() : base(LayoutRoot) // LayoutRoot isn't available here
    {
    } 
}

public class GMPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public GMPage(Grid LayoutRoot)
    {
    }
}
```

Passing "this" also doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally found a solution. It isn't awesome I think, but it is much better, that dublication code, of course.

I just added special method to base class:

```
public class GMPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public void PagePreparation(Grid LayoutRoot)
    {
    }
}

public EventsPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    PagePreparation(LayoutRoot);
}
```